# Memory ownership in PKCS #11 C_FindObjects where ulMaxObjectCount != 1

Tags: cryptography, pkcs#11

The authors of PKCS #11 v2.40 utilize a common pattern when an API returns a variable length list of items. In APIs such as `C_GetSlotList` and `C_GetMechanismList`, the application is expected to call the APIs twice. In the first invocation, a pointer to a `CK_ULONG` is set to the number of items that will be returned on the next invocation. This allows the application to allocate enough memory and invoke the API again to retrieve the results.

The `C_FindObjects` call also returns a variable number of items, but it uses a different paradigm. The parameter `CK_OBJECT_HANDLE_PTR phObject` is set to the head of the result list. The parameter `CK_ULONG_PTR pulObjectCount` is set to the number of items returned, which is ensured to be less than `CK_ULONG ulMaxObjectCount`.

The standard does not explicitly say that `phObject` must be a valid pointer to a block of memory large enough to hold `ulMaxObjectCount` `CK_OBJECT_HANDLE`s.

One could interpret the standard as meaning that the application must pessimistically allocate enough memory for `ulMaxObjectCount` objects. Alternately, one could interpret the standard as meaning that the PKCS #11 implementation will allocate `pulObjectCount` `CK_OBJECT_HANDLE`s and it is then the application's responsibility to free that memory. This later interpretation seems suspect however, as no where else in the standard does the implementation of PKCS #11 ever allocate memory.

The passage is:

```
C_FindObjects continues a search for token and session objects that 
match a template, obtaining additional object handles. hSession is 
the session’s handle; phObject points to the location that receives 
the list (array) of additional object handles; ulMaxObjectCount is 
the maximum number of object handles to be returned; pulObjectCount 
points to the location that receives the actual number of object 
handles returned.

If there are no more objects matching the template, then the location 
that pulObjectCount points to receives the value 0.

The search MUST have been initialized with C_FindObjectsInit.
```

The non-normative example is not very helpful, as it sets `ulMaxObjectCount` to 1. It does, however, allocate the memory for that one entry. Which seems to indicate that the application must pessimistically pre-allocate the memory.

```
CK_SESSION_HANDLE hSession;
CK_OBJECT_HANDLE hObject;
CK_ULONG ulObjectCount;
CK_RV rv;
.
.
rv = C_FindObjectsInit(hSession, NULL_PTR, 0);
assert(rv == CKR_OK);
while (1) {
 rv = C_FindObjects(hSession, &hObject, 1, &ulObjectCount);
 if (rv != CKR_OK || ulObjectCount == 0)
 break;
 .
 .
}
rv = C_FindObjectsFinal(hSession);
assert(rv == CKR_OK);
```

Specification Link: http://docs.oasis-open.org/pkcs11/pkcs11-base/v2.40/pkcs11-base-v2.40.pdf

Comment: I agree, it's borderline. Although it's likely that someone on S.O. has insight into how memory is generally managed, it's almost certain that someone here has used the PKCS#11 C library specifically.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Yes, it would appear that the application is responsible for allocating space for the object handles returned by `C_FindObjects()`.  The example code does this, even though it only requests a single object handle at a time, and so should you.

You could just as well rewrite the example code to request multiple object handles, e.g. like this:

```c
#define MAX_OBJECT_COUNT 100  /* arbitrary value */

K_SESSION_HANDLE hSession;
CK_OBJECT_HANDLE hObjects[MAX_OBJECT_COUNT];
CK_ULONG ulObjectCount, i;
CK_RV rv;

rv = C_FindObjectsInit(hSession, NULL_PTR, 0);
assert(rv == CKR_OK);
while (1) {
  rv = C_FindObjects(hSession, hObjects, MAX_OBJECT_COUNT, &ulObjectCount);
  if (rv != CKR_OK || ulObjectCount == 0) break;
  for (i = 0; i < ulObjectCount; i++) {
    /* do something with hObjects[i] here */
  }
}
rv = C_FindObjectsFinal(hSession);
assert(rv == CKR_OK);
```

Presumably, the ability to request multiple object handles in a single `C_FindObjects()` call is intended as a performance optimization.

FWIW, this is pretty much exactly how many C standard library functions like [`fread()`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009695399/functions/fread.html) work as well.  It'd be extremely inefficient to read data from a file one byte at a time with `fgetc()`, so the `fread()` function lets you allocate an arbitrarily large buffer and read as much data as will fit into it.

Comment: Thanks, just wanted to verify. I guess the difference between C_GetSlotList and C_FindObjects is that the library likely knows ahead of time exactly how many slots exist, but might not know the number of matching objects?

Comment: That could indeed be one reason for the different API styles. It could also be that C_FindObjects is expected to sometimes return many more results that C_GetSlotList, so that allocating a single buffer to hold them all might not be feasible. Or there might be internal implementation issues that would make resuming a partial C_GetSlotList query impractical. Or the different parts of the API might just have been designed by different people with different API design preferences.

Comment: (Personally, I frankly find the C_GetSlotList API style rather inelegant, and often inefficient and rather annoying to use -- especially given that, as noted on page 73, there's no guarantee that the size returned on the first call *actually is enough* for the results of the second call, since the number of results might have changed in the mean time. Given a choice, I'd much prefer a C_FindObjects style API, even if it means having to set up and free a separate session object.)